# javascript parsing a string for negative numbers (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to parse a string that includes negative numbers.

**Example input:**

```
let str = '-3+2+(3-2)';
```

**Desired output:**

```
['-3','+','2','+','(','3','-','2',')']
```

**My code:**

```
str=str.replace(/\s+/g,'');
str=str.replace(/--/g,'+');
str=str.replace(/\(/g,',(,');    
str=str.replace(/\)/g,',),');
str=str.replace(/\//g,',/,');
str=str.replace(/\*/g,',*,');  
str=str.replace(/\+/g,',+,');
str=str.replace(/\,+/g,',');
let arr=str.split(','); //
```

**Actual output:**

```
[ -3 ,+,2,+,(,   3-2 ,)]
```

**Question:** How do I achieve my desired output?

Comment: What a you trying to achieve here? What would you do after splitting? Next step?

Comment: I would like to parse the string into an array to look like [**-3**,+,2,+,(,3,-,2,)]. The problem is when I try to parse it with -, I end up creating [**-,3**,+,2+,(3,-,2)]

Comment: @Snorkals, are you trying to implement calc?

Comment: Yes. Pretty much. Not allowed to use eval for example.

Comment: If you really just want to calculate the end result, take a look at the demo parser here https://pegjs.org/online . Otherwise, why not treat every number-number as an addition?

Comment: I think it's hard to acheive what you claim is desired output, particularly within the parentheses at the end: `'3','-','2'`.  It would be much easier if there was no need to separate the `-` from the subsequent `2`, instead yielding `-2`.  After all, it seems like all you want to do is to add each number encounter, so get rid of the parentheses as well, they are not needed in that case.  If your requirements are different on the other hand, you will need to state them more explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this pattern, [-+(-)]

```
var str = ['-3','+','2','+','(','3','-','2',')']
str.map (a => a.replace(/[-+\(\)]/g, ''))
```

yields,

```
["3", "", "2", "", "", "3", "", "2", ""]
```

I guess that is what you are after, replacing -, +, ) with empty space.

Comment: Originally, I had done this but the problem I faced is when I attempt to parse a large mathematical problem, traversing the array and removing spaces end up killing my run time.

Comment: Well that is what happens if you do lot of synchronous task at once. You could parse one string at a time. Even then the patter and parsing process remains same.